# Is it a bug that I can upvote a question a second time after it was migrated?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, migration

This [Stack Exchange question](https://superuser.com/questions/1524576/changing-assetbundle-build-outside-of-unity?noredirect=1#comment2310487_1524576) which I up-voted on Stack Exchange was migrated to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176524/changing-assetbundle-build-outside-of-unity) and I was able to up-vote it again. Thus, as of now it has 2 upvotes from one user (me).

Is that a bug?

Comment: I don't think that it is...the identities aren't linked in such a way that your previous vote on another site would prevent you from voting again.

Comment: Maybe kinda sort of a bug. Although, I doubt it's big enough to really matter - you won't really get to cheat the system to a sufficient degree with double voting a migrated question. And whether or not voting on each site is intended or not and should be prevented or not is arguable anyway. Overall, no big problem.